# How to change Application Culture in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, cultureinfo

Here is my code.

```
double value = double.Parse(Utility.GetParamValueOrDefault(omRecord.paramList[i].value, "0"),CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

this is the error i'm getting 
**FormatException: 
Input string was not in a correct format**

i have read some threads of StackOverFlow saying i need to add into main() of my WPF application the following code.

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
FrameworkElement.LanguageProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(FrameworkElement), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.IetfLanguageTag)));
```

i still get the same error and my CurrentCulture is still not en-US.

Comment: *Thread.CurrentThread* that's for one thread only - are you sure the code you show runs in that thread, not in another one?

Comment: it runs in another thread how do i set it for the whole app?

Comment: where do you put that parsing logic? in a new thread like BackgroundWorker? and setting up the culture should be done in the beginning of the application

Comment: @YuliamChandra it is done in main() of app.xaml.cs, how do i set the culture for the whole app?

Comment: Why not to pass culture you want to parsing function itself (`double.Parse("1.3", new CultureInfo("en-US")`?

Comment: Why change the default culture, instead of specifying that culture in the parse method?!

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov in every line in the code i parse something i need to do that?

Comment: @Gilad - do you have problem with specifying culture? Running code analysis for production code may be good idea and you'll get [CA1304 :Specify CultureInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182189.aspx) warning for all parse / format functions without it...

Comment: @thanks everyone i just need to put the default thread and not a specific thread.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

try this

```
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
```

Answer (score 6):

At the start of your application you can set CultureInfo in this way

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
```

If you want to determine the CultureInfo at runtime try this:

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo currentCulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
```

For English language there is this table :-)

```
en          en-US       English
en-029      en-029      English (Caribbean)
en-AU       en-AU       English (Australia)
en-BZ       en-BZ       English (Belize)
en-CA       en-CA       English (Canada)
en-GB       en-GB       English (United Kingdom)
en-IE       en-IE       English (Ireland)
en-JM       en-JM       English (Jamaica)
en-NZ       en-NZ       English (New Zealand)
en-PH       en-PH       English (Republic of the Philippines)
en-TT       en-TT       English (Trinidad and Tobago)
en-US       en-US       English (United States)
en-ZA       en-ZA       English (South Africa)
en-ZW       en-ZW       English (Zimbabwe)
```

And here is a link for all languages https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim/Country_Codes