# How to change the culture?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to change the language with a button click with the code:

```
private void Spache_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("fr-FR");

    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("fr-FR");          
}
```

My application has some resource files: `Resources.ar-TN.resx`, `Resources.fr-FR.resx` etc... I need to switch the languages with a button. It works in tha main, but in the button it doesn't work.

Comment: You can only set it once in the application. If you want to change it you will have to close it and restart the application

Comment: You need to reload your UI. Culture changes do not propagate everywhere. Safest is a restart of the app.

Comment: but how ? I am a beginner .

Comment: Help me pLz ...

Comment: @Barbarous *don't* try things at random. Localization is WPF is *thoroughly* documented, with a lot of tutorials, courses and How Tos. `CurrentCulture` doesn't affect which resources are loaded. Changing the CurrentUICulture won't force the form to reload itself.

Comment: @Barbarous You don't need to hard-code the culture in the first place, WPF already uses the end user's locale settings to load the appropriate UI and resources. In France, it will load the french resources automatically

Comment: Check [WPF Globalization and Localization Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/wpf-globalization-and-localization-overview)

Comment: Also check Pluralsight's [Introduction to Localization and Globalization in .NET](https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/intro-to-localization-globalization-dotnet) course. The example application is a WPF application. The course will explain how .NET detects the user's desired culture, how `CurrentCulture` affects *parsing and formatting* but not the UI, while `CurrentUICulture` affects the UI, but not parsing/formatting.

Answer (score 0):

The actual question should be :

> How can I reload the UI after changing the UI culture?

The property that affects the UI is `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture`, *not* `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture`. The second culture affects how strings are parsed or formatted. `CurrentUICulture` is the culture used to load localized resources.

Changing `CurrentUICulture` doesn't *reload* those resources. You'll have to force a reload explicitly or reload the application's main window.

Check [Changing Culture in WPF](https://jeremybytes.blogspot.com/2013/07/changing-culture-in-wpf.html), written by the author of Pluralsight's course [Introduction to Localization and Globalization in .NET](https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/intro-to-localization-globalization-dotnet). That course uses a WPF application as an example, so be sure to go through it. You can get 3 months of free access to Pluralsight's courses through Microsoft's (free) [Visual Studio Dev Essentials](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/dev-essentials/) offer.

What the article shows, is how handle the main window explicitly and reload it when the culture changes.

`App.xaml` is modified to prevent the Main window from opening automatically. The StartupUri is removed from `App.xaml and the`OnStartup` event is handled to open the main window explicitly. This  :

```
<Application x:Class="WpfLocalized.App"
             ...
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
...
</Application>
```

Changes to :

```
<Application x:Class="WpfLocalized.App"
             ...
             >
...
</Application>
```

And the following code is added to `App.xaml.cs` :

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);
        Application.Current.MainWindow = new MainWindow();
        Application.Current.MainWindow.Show();
    }

    public static void ChangeCulture(CultureInfo newCulture)
    {
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = newCulture;
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = newCulture;

        var oldWindow = Application.Current.MainWindow;            


        Application.Current.MainWindow = new MainWindow();
        Application.Current.MainWindow.Show();

        oldWindow.Close();
    }
}
```

The `OnStartup` method loads the main window the first time. `ChangeCulture` changes the culture, *closes* the current window and loads it again, thus reloading all resources.

To change the culture and reload all one has to do is call `App.ChangeCulture` eg from a button click :

```
    private void AUButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        App.ChangeCulture(new CultureInfo("en-AU"));

    }
```

The article's example has a single Textbox whose value is loaded from the resources and some buttons that change the culture:

```
    <TextBlock
            Text="{x:Static resx:Resources.Greeting}"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center" Padding="10,5"
            Margin="5"/>
```

Each time the window is loaded, the resource will be loaded from the correct file based on the CurrentUICulture

Answer (score -1):

There is a similiar question in another topic, check it out it may be correct

[See if this helps u](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24135675/how-to-change-application-culture-in-wpf)

Comment: This should be a comment. It doesn't *answer* the question. That question is about something completely different too

Comment: The question is about changing the culture of the app isnt it? Well thanks anyway

Comment: No it isn't. It's about a specific parsing error. The answers shows the same code the OP used. They *don't* show how to reload the resources

Comment: @Barbarous why do you want to do that? WPF will display the correct resources automatically based on the user's culture.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos i want to change the language with a button in my app